# maxlength and minlength does not work in bootstrap 5

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I was trying to give a maxlength and minlength to an input in the bootstrap 5.
But it seems like It does not work for me . Can you fix the problem please ?!
Here is the code:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="mb-3">
  <label for="phone-number" class="form-lable" style="font-family: 'yekan';"> f_name : </label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control mt-1" name="f_name" id="phone-number" required minlength="5" maxlength="40">
  <div class="form-text">some text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code is working, you can't write more than 40 characters and if you have less than 5 if you mouse over the input it will notify that you need at least 5 characters.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure but just remove required and run

id="phone-number" **required** minlength="5" maxlength="40">

Comment: How does removing required attribute help?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).